# Starting and stopping a sound with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I need to start a sound effect at will... I need it to be stopped as well before it is over.  I'm doing this all in JavaScript.  How would I go about this?  I've never used sounds before in a page (normally not a good thing to use sounds, this project requires me to).

Any help would be appreciated :)

If it means anything, I'm also utilizing jQuery.

Comment: what about the HTML5 audio element? It'll only work in IE9+ tho.

Comment: I need this to run on old browsers.  The school I am at uses crummy old IE browsers that are passed their death date.

Comment: Is this a looped sound?  I remember using the javascript start and stop sound functions, but was never happy with the delays that I got when using them.  Instead, I ended up just playing the sound constantly, but adjusting the volume from 0 to whatever instead of turning the sound on and off.  That, for whatever reason, reacted in a much better fashion, time wise.  Of course, that was also 10+ years ago.  Mostly likely not at all applicable now.

Comment: if sound == bgsound element, it will also produce awful problems in Opera (it supports <bugsound> but its DOM interface is very crappy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jquery, have you tried the [sound](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/sound) plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [SoundsManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)